# how to print inside a textinput, all positions of an array? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im new in react-native, im making a note bloc to get started, but something that its getting me crazy is do the line break after inserted a photo, something like this:

[image]

as you can see, theres the title and below the content, its text the a photo then a line break and the continue to write below, this is the thing that i dont know how to do it in react, so im trying this:

constructor:

```
this.state = {
        title: "",
        content: ["",""],
        note_number: "",
        fetch_notes: "",
        img: "",
    }
```

content its an array, where index 0 will be for text and index 1 for images, heres the render function:

```
     render() {
        return (
            <>
            <View style = {this.styles.container}> 
                <View style = {this.styles.textinput_container}>
                    <TextInput style = {this.styles.TextInput_title} placeholder = "Title" multiline = {true} maxLength = {80} value = {this.state.title} onChangeText = {title => this.setState({title: title})}></TextInput>
                    <TextInput placeholder = "Content" multiline = {true} value = {this.state.content[0]} onChangeText = {text => this.setState( state => ({content:[text, this.state.content[1]]}))}>
                    </TextInput>
                </View>
                <View style = {this.styles.image}>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Button title = "Add image" onPress = {this.add_Image}></Button>
                    <Button title = "Save Changes" onPress = {this.save_Changes}></Button>
                </View>
            </View>
         )
      }
```

with this i just printing the firts position of content, just text, but, how do i do to print the second position? where the image saved,

this:

```
<TextInput placeholder = "Content" multiline = {true}
value = {this.state.content[0]} onChangeText = {text => this.setState( state => ({content:[text, 
this.state.content[1]]}))}>
{this.state.content[1]}
</TextInput>
```

or this:

```
<TextInput placeholder = "Content" multiline = {true}
value = {this.state.content[0]} onChangeText = {text => this.setState( state => ({content:[text, 
this.state.content[1]]}))}>
<Text>{this.state.content[1]}</Text>
</TextInput>
```

neither of them work, it gives me the error:

[image]

how can i do it? th

Comment: As the error clearly says, you are giving value to your text input and also trying to render child inside it. That is why you are getting error.

Comment: mmm, i see it now, but, how can do to implement that?

Comment: Simply use View as a wrapper , https://reactnative.dev/docs/view

Comment: if i use it, and make a line break, can i still write below the image inserted?